# Custom validation errors gets set multiple times

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I created a custom validation for one of my models properties the following way:

```
Model.validateAsync('minOsVersion', validateMinimumOsVersion, {message: 'Minimum OS Version incorrect'});
function validateMinimumOsVersion(err, done) {
    var requiredVersion = "some version";
    var givenVersion = this.minOsVersion;
    if (validator.validateSemanticVersionString(givenVersion, requiredVersion) < 0) {
      err('too_low');
    }
    done();
  }
```

This validation works fine, except the validation gets called multiple times (still no problem) but then adds the "minimum os version too low" error multiple times to the returned error object ob loopback.

[image: returned data]

Am i missing something or why is this error populated 12 times? if the validation for this specific case fails it should only be added once.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
As per request, here is the other code that gets called after my upload method

```
Model.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance) {
      analyseMetadata(ctx.instance, function(error, model) {
        if (error) { return next(error); }
        next();
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });

  function analyseMetadata(model, cb) {
    extractMetadata(model, function(error, data){
      if (error) { return cb(error); }

      if (data && data.provisioning && data.metadata && data.entitlements) {
        model.updateAttribute("expires", data.provisioning.ExpirationDate);
        model.updateAttribute("created", data.provisioning.CreationDate);

        model.updateAttribute("appIdentifier", data.entitlements['application-identifier']);
        model.updateAttribute("teamIdentifier", data.entitlements['com.apple.developer.team-identifier']);

        model.updateAttribute("bundleIdentifier", data.metadata.CFBundleIdentifier);
        model.updateAttribute("displayName", data.metadata.CFBundleDisplayName);
        model.updateAttribute("bundleName", data.metadata.CFBundleName);
        model.updateAttribute("shortVersion", data.metadata.CFBundleShortVersionString);
        model.updateAttribute("bundleVersion", data.metadata.CFBundleVersion);
        model.updateAttribute("minOsVersion", data.metadata.MinimumOSVersion);
        model.updateAttribute("builtOsVersion", data.metadata.DTPlatformVersion);
      }
      cb(null, model);
    });
  }
```

what would be a better way to update attributes while uploading but not generating the validations multiple times

Comment: What does that `upload` endpoint do? It looks like the endpoint you're hitting is not a standard (generated) model endpoint, so my guess is that there could be some loop somewhere that hits the model multiple times, thus generating multiple errors. I think we'd need to see the endpoint code to know for sure.

Comment: yeah, you're totally right. i do some `updateAttribute` calls on the object in an `before safe` hook. i'm uploading a file on this endpoint, unpizzing it and extracting some metainformations that then get updated using `updateAtrribute` before the http request gets returned (and eventually throwing back the validations of that metadata check).

Comment: @jakerella i added some missing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the reason you're getting multiple validation errors is that you're calling `updateAttribute()` multiple times. Instead, consider using [`updateAttributes()` (plural form)](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-prototype-updateattributes) which should only invoke the validation method(s) once:

```
function analyseMetadata(model, cb) {
  extractMetadata(model, function(error, data){
    if (error) { return cb(error); }

    if (data && data.provisioning && data.metadata && data.entitlements) {
      model.updateAttributes({
        "expires": data.provisioning.ExpirationDate,
        "created": data.provisioning.CreationDate,
        "appIdentifier": data.entitlements['application-identifier'],
        // ...
      }, function updateCallback(updateErr, updatedModel) {
        if (updateErr) { return cb(updateErr); }

        cb(null, updatedModel);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Note also that I added the callback for updating attributes. This is an asynchronous function and actually performs the update, so you need to execute your `cb()` callback *after* it is complete.

Comment: thanks @jakerella, this fixed it. also thanks for the async note.